# How to access variables of form in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I am setting ng-show directive on span and i want to set the expression value from controller based on response value but i am struggling to access that expression in controller and set it with value true.

**here is my html code**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float>
                    <input type="mobile" name="mobile" ng-model="vm.form.mobile" placeholder="Mobile"
                           ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]*" required>
                    <div ng-messages="loginForm.mobile.$error" role="alert" multiple>
                        <div ng-message="required">
                            <span >Mobile is required</span>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-message="pattern">
                            <span >Mobile must be a valid </span>
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="true">Sorry, Mobile no. is not registered.</span>
                    </div>

</md-input-container>
```

**And this is my controller**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.pages.auth.login')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function LoginController(msApi)
    {
        // Data
        var vm = this;

        vm.login = login;


        // Methods
       function login(){
            var jsonData = {"mobile":vm.form.mobile};
            msApi.request('login.credentials@save',jsonData,
                // SUCCESS
                function (response)
                {
                   console.log(response.error);
                    if(response.error == 1){
                        vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = true;
                    }
                },
                // ERROR
                function (response)
                {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            )
       }
        //////////
    }
})();
```

Comment: assign ng-show to function and return true or false from controller function or in your case you can do it as ng-show="vm.form.mobileErrorFlag"

Comment: ng-show="error()"  like this @Vinod.

Comment: you can use there a variable and change it based on condition i.e true or false

Comment: I am accessing it in controller. check it in above controller but still it is not working.

Comment: @SameerDighe you already have taht variable see my above comment use vm.form.mobileErrorFlag directly change this   <span ng-show="vm.form.mobileErrorFlag">Sorry, Mobile no. is not registered.</span>

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the variable **vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = false;**

```
function LoginController(msApi)
{
    // Data
    var vm = this;
    vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = false;
    vm.login = login;


    // Methods
   function login(){
        var jsonData = {"mobile":vm.form.mobile};
        msApi.request('login.credentials@save',jsonData,
            // SUCCESS
            function (response)
            {
               console.log(response.error);
                if(response.error == 1){
                    vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = true;
                }
            },
            // ERROR
            function (response)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        )
   }
    //////////
}
})();
```